# Search predecessor of a key in a sorted array using binary search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

For a sorted int array, the BS algorithm returns the predecessor of the key.

For example, given array {3, 5, 7, 9, 11}, BS(15) = 11, BS(9) = 7. You can define the behavior of the algorithm when predecessor does not exist in the array (e.g. BS(3)). I think the solution is a variation of the binary search algorithm, but I cannot get the correct one. This is what I have so far, it is incorrect:

```
int BinarySearch5(vector<int> &data, int left, int right, int key) {
  // if pred does not exist in the array, then return the smallest element in the array
  if (left >= right) {
    return left;
  } 
  int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
  if (data[mid] >= key) {  // search left
    return BinarySearch5(data, left, mid - 1, key);
  } else {  // data[mid] < key, search right but including mid
    return BinarySearch5(data, mid, right, key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would give a segmentation fault if the key value was greater than the largest value in you vector. If a key 20 was given for your vector `{3, 5, 7, 9, 11}`, `BS(0,4)` would call `BS(2,4)`, then `BS(3,4)`, then again `BS(3,4)` and on and on. So once `data[mid] > key` we know that `mid` is a *possible* answer. But if there is an element less than `data[mid]` and located to the right of `mid`, that element's position should be the answer.

One possible way to avoid that problem is below: store `mid` as an answer. If `BS(mid+1,r)` gives a value `ind` such that `data[ind] > key`, we return `ind` instead of `mid`. Else return `mid`.

---

```
int BinarySearch5(vector<int> &data, int left, int right, int key) {
  if (left >= right) {
    return left;
  }

  int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
  if (data[mid] >= key) {
    return BinarySearch5(data, left, mid - 1, key);
  } else {
    int t = BinarySearch5(data, mid+1, right, key); // See the change here
    return data[t]<key? t:mid;
  }
}
```